# Update existing row data using a userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am using a userform to update existing data on a worksheet.  I can 
create new records just fine.  I created an update userform with a 
combobox to search for the names.  It pulls the persons data just fine and I am able to change the information.  But when I go to click the update button, an error occurs.  Before it was adding a totally new line which I did not want to happen so I adjusted my code.  I just want to update an existing line of data with the edited information.

I have tried to use the MATCH function in VBA after it was replicating records.

```
Private Sub Update_record_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
Dim n As Long
Dim empname As String

empname = Application.Match(VBA.CStr(Me.Update_record.Value), 
sh.Range("C:C"), 0)

sh.Range("A" & empname).Value = Me.First_Name.Value
sh.Range("B" & empname).Value = Me.Last_Name.Value
sh.Range("D" & empname).Value = Me.MainPX.Value
sh.Range("E" & empname).Value = Me.AltPX.Value
sh.Range("F" & empname).Value = Me.Job_Role.Value
sh.Range("G" & empname).Value = Me.WristBand.Value
sh.Range("H" & empname).Value = Me.Team.Value
sh.Range("I" & empname).Value = Me.Unit.Value


Range("A2:J" & n).Sort key1:=Range("A2:A" & n), order1:=xlAscending, 
Header:=xlNo

 Me.First_Name.Value = ""
 Me.Last_Name.Value = ""
 Me.MainPX.Value = ""
 Me.AltPX.Value = ""
 Me.Job_Role.Value = ""
 Me.WristBand.Value = ""
 Me.Team.Value = ""
 Me.Unit.Value = ""


 MsgBox "Record has been updated", vbInformation
 End Sub
```

This is where the application is erroring out...It stops here....on this line

```
empname = Application.Match(VBA.CStr(Me.Update_record.Value), 
sh.Range("C:C"), 0)
```

So the data never gets updated to the row.  Below are two screen shots... one of the worksheet and one of the userform.

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

[image: Userform Screenshot]

Comment: What's the error? Also, you start off with `sh.Range` qualified `Range` calls, and then sort with unqualified `Range("A2:J" & n).Sort Key1:=Range(...)` ...they should be qualified as well. But `Match` will return a `Variant/Error` if it doesn't find a match, and you're coercing that return value into a `String` -- I'm betting the error you're getting is a *type mismatch*.

Comment: Always capture the result of `Application.AnyLateBoundWorksheetFunction` into a `Variant`, then only proceed to treat that value as something usable when `Not IfError(thatVariantResult)`.

Comment: What does `Me.Update_Record.Value` look like? Is it more like `54204` or more like `CA0041`? If the former (i.e. a numeric ID), then `CStr` could be responsible for `Match` failing.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon... the error is a "Runtime Error 13" Type Mismatch...and it highlights that line when I ask it to debug....I'm lost as to why.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  I even changed empname to Long instead of string and got the same error.

Comment: See answer below. Nothing but a `Variant` should hold the result of `Application.Match`.

Comment: Where does the value of `Me.Update_record` come from? FWIW an "employee name" is a rather bad unique key to have.

Comment: Please tell me `Me.Update_record` isn't the big "update record" button.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon....yes...I take that is one of the problems?  I am trying to get them to add the employee number to differentiate the employees.

Comment: Well, you're looking up *the value of a button* (which is an utterly irrelevant `Boolean` value) in a column that contains employee names. The match is *always* going to fail... unless someone is named `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Regardless -- capturing the result of `Application.Match` in anything other than a `Variant` is going to blow up with a *type mismatch* one day or another.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon...I am new to VBA and trying to learn... maybe this is too complex too soon for me.... I am frustrated as heck.  The combox pulls the data into the fields but I still don't understand how to get the rows to update.Thank you for your patience and help though.  I am all ears.  Would it help if I add a field for employee number and set my Match to that?

Comment: You want the `Match` to use something from the form (hard to tell from the screenshots... could it be that "search full name" box?) that exists in column C. `empname` is a misnommer - it's really a row number, so you want it to be a `Long`, but again you will want to capture the `Match` result into a `Variant` first and make sure `IsError(theMatchResult)` is `False` before you treat that result as a `Long`. An employee code/number would be much more reliable than a name, yes =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon...Thank you for those.  I no longer have a problem searching for the row to populate the update form. I have added a column for ID now and I am going to try and write back to the worksheet to overwrite the existing data and perform the update.  That is where my sticking point is. So you prefer option 3 that you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways that I can immediatley think to go about it. I haven't tested the first two so let me know if you face any problem.

**WAY ONE**

```
Dim fName As String
Dim lName As String
Dim NameToSearch As String
Dim RecRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

fName = FirstNameTextbox.Value '<~~ First Name textBox
lName = LastNameTextbox.Value  '<~~ Last Name textBox

NameToSearch = fName & ", " & lName

empname = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(NameToSearch, sh.Range("C:C"), 0)
```

**WAY TWO**

This method uses `.Find`.

```
Dim fName As String
Dim lName As String
Dim NameToSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim RecRow As Long

fName = FirstNameTextbox.Value
lName = LastNameTextbox.Value

NameToSearch = fName & ", " & lName

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

With ws
    Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=NameToSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        RecRow = aCell.Row '<~~ This is the row where the data is
    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
    End If
End With
```

**WAY THREE (I prefer This)**

Insert a column in the worksheet in Col A and call it `ID`. This will have unique serial numbers(row numbers?). When reading the item, read that as well and when writing it back to the cells, use that `ID` to write back. No need to search for the record using `Match` or `.Find`

In this case you will always update the row `(ID + 1)` assuming, the serial number starts at 1 from row 2.

Comment: WAY THREE. These type out of box performance boosters make working in Excel VBA enjoyable. Always looking for such ideas.